# Inner join have multiple ON clauses into last join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing maintenance to OLD sql database  and I have a select clause like this:

```
SELECT
              [P].[ItemID]
            , SUM([p].[OnOrder]) AS [OnOrder]
            , [I].[FullName] AS [PartNo]
            , [I].[PurchaseDesc] AS [Description]
            , [I].[ItemCust3]
              FROM @POItems AS [P]
                  INNER JOIN [tblMakeUseType] AS [MUT] WITH(NOLOCK)
                  INNER JOIN [ItemInventory] AS [I] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [MUT].[MakeUseTypeID] = [I].[MakeUseTypeID] ON [P].[ItemID] = [I].[NCItemInventoryID]
```

As you can see first `INNER JOIN` does not have `ON` clause, but after second inner join there is `ON` clause of first `INNER JOIN`, I never seen that before, is there any way to do reverse engeneering and use as tipcal `INNER JOIN`? I mean each one with hes `ON` clause? Regards

Comment: A join where you make a UNCONDITIONAL join of two tables is called a [**CROSS JOIN**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/cross-join). Basically it will create a cartesian product ot the rows of those tables. When I see a query like you posted I assume someone forgot a ON clause =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is interpreted as:

```
FROM @POItems [P] INNER JOIN
     ([tblMakeUseType] [MUT] INNER JOIN
      [ItemInventory] [I] 
      ON [MUT].[MakeUseTypeID] = [I].[MakeUseTypeID]
     )
    ON [P].[ItemID] = [I].[NCItemInventoryID]
```

This is fine.  But you can write it more conventionally as:

```
FROM [tblMakeUseType] [MUT] INNER JOIN
     [ItemInventory] [I] 
     ON [MUT].[MakeUseTypeID] = [I].[MakeUseTypeID] INNER JOIN
     @POItems [P]
     ON [P].[ItemID] = [I].[NCItemInventoryID]
```

Or:

```
FROM @POItems [P] INNER JOIN
     [ItemInventory] [I] 
     ON [P].[ItemID] = [I].[NCItemInventoryID] INNER JOIN
     [tblMakeUseType] [MUT]
     ON [MUT].[MakeUseTypeID] = [I].[MakeUseTypeID]
```

The order of the tables does not matter for *inner* joins, although the tables have to be declared before their aliases can be used for `ON` conditions.

Comment: Any chance you can point to documentation on this usage? My understand has always been that it forces an order of joins within the SQL Server engine, but this was always stated without documentation. So, while it will produce the same results, it executes it differently.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean . . . The order of the execution of joins should be determined in the optimization phase of the compiler.  Parentheses in the `FROM` clause should have no affect on this.  Note that although order is irrelevant for *inner* joins, order makes a big difference for *outer* joins.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was talking only about inner joins. I just tested and didn't see a difference in an execution plan between an ON at each join or at the end. Just odd I can't find any documentation on that; my Google-fu has failed me.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean . . . I find it hard to find *official* information about the SQL Server optimizer in general.  There is a hint (pun intended) in the documentation that ordering is determined by the compiler because of the existence of the `FORCE ORDER` hint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017).